# How to add an optional Parameter in Mysql and Node.js express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to call a node.js express api linked with a mysql database and I use `req.query` to enter parameters but my plan is to make them optional. 
My query gets all restaurants in a certain radius of a point of interest. This is working fine, but I would like to be able to extend this.
I would like to be able to get all restaurants with a certain name in a radius of a point of interest.
For example, I woulds like to `get all McDonalds in a 500 metre radius of the main square.`

I would also like to get all restaurants with a certain name and type in a radius of a point of interest.
For example I would like to `get steakhouses called Jerry in a 500 metre radius of the main square`.

My Query is of the form

```
SELECT restaurants.*, < Calculating Radius> AS distance FROM restaurants 
  CROSS JOIN poi WHERE   poi.name like '%"+req.query.poi+"%' AND <Calculating Radius> 
< "+req.query.radius+" AND restaurants.type like '%"+req.query.type+"%'";
```

The Problem is that if I do not add the `type` parameter I get no results.

I assume my problem is in this part of the query `AND restaurants.type like '%"+req.query.type+"%'";` but for the life of me I can't find problem.

How can I make it that I can combine these criteria but if I leave one or two out, it should work. 
What am I missing from my query.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you check "req.query.type" value before firing the query and make appropriate changes like if the type is undefined don't include  "req.query.type otherwise include it in the query

Comment: sure, but if `'%"+req.query.type+"%'` is empty then should it not be `%%` and therefore a wildcard?

Comment: I think your req.query.type is undefined..thats why its resulting like that

Comment: just print the req.query.type and comment here what is the value

Comment: ok, I did that and if I leave  type out, then I get undefined but if I add it, it prints the value,

Comment: Please check all the parameters before firing the query..its a good coding practise also